# How to start with open API in corda 4.3?

Tags: corda, openapi

I am trying to use open API in Corda 4.3, please guide me how to start the same?

Answer (score 0):

Corda-RPC client library gives you a proxy which can be used to make RPC calls to a running Corda node. This library needs to be included on your client-side.

Traditionally, you will write a web server, expose web services, use Corda-RPC client to connect to the node. In your web application, you can call these exposed web services. You can expose Open API spec compatible web services and use open api to generate the client library. 
Writing web services looks like an easy task, but much time can be spent in handling issues like CORS, JWT handling etc

Another option is to use a [Braid](https://gitlab.com/bluebank/braid/tree/master) server, which connects to your node, generates Open API endpoints. 
Then [Open Api connector](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) can be used to generate the client library (currently, this client library can be generated in more than 40 languages). 
Include this library in your client application.

Steps

1. Start Corda nodes
2. Start Braid Server by running BraidMainKt by specifying the following parameters -

   - a.    RPC host, port, user, password (You configure this in your
     node)
   - b.    Port at which Braid server should expose the endpoints.
   - c.   Open Api specification version, which the endpoints should be
     compatible against
   - d.    Path to CorDapp folder within the node
3. Now you have Open Api compatible endpoints exposed by Braid server.
4. Run open-api generator to generate the client library by specifying the following parameters

   - a.    Swagger base URL exposed by Braid
   - b.    Which language to generate the API in
   - c.    Output folder, where the generated API file should be kept
   - d.    The package name for Api
   - e.    The model name for Api

Below example is a react web application which uses Open Api generated Apis to connect to Braid Server which in turn connects to the Corda node.

https://github.com/corda/openapi-sample